# Blueimp adding upload trigger to multiple inputs

Tags: javascript, blueimp

I have two inputs with `type="file"` on my page like so

```
<input class="form-control" type="file" id="uploadImageFileSingle"> <br>
<input id="fileupload" type="file" name="files[]" multiple>
```

The first input is a normal input for uploading a single file. The second input is used by blueimp to upload multiple files and is initialized like so:

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    url: url,
    dataType: 'json',
    ....
})
```

Everything is working correctly except for this one thing: When I add a file to the first input, it is triggering the `fileuploadadd` method of blueimp and the file is added the blueimp queue to be uploaded. I can't figure how/why this is happening.

How can I adjust what inputs get picked up by blueimp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one work around:

```
$("#uploadImageFileSingle").off() // removes all handlers from first input
```

Be aware that this will remove **all** handlers from this input element but it worked for me because it also removes the handler that got added by blueimp (still can't figure out where that is getting added!).

Answer (score 0):

if you have the button

```
<button id="upload_btn">Multiple Upload</button>
```

You can try with

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
dataType: 'json',
add: function (e, data) {
    var that = this;
    $.blueimp.fileupload.prototype.options.add.call(that, e, data);
    $("#upload_btn").on('click', function () {
        data.submit();
    });
},
});
```

Maybe it controls better way to load multiple files